# Courier fails to save copy in sent folders on emails with large attachments

Tags: email, postfix, configuration, courier-imap

I use postfix and courier on my email server on debian 11. Whenever I send an email with attachments larger than a few MB (I use a slow cellphone-connection), it fails on saving the copy in the Sent folder.

The email is successfully sent, only the copy fails. Smaller emails are copied into the Sent folder fine (I use only IMAP-ssl, in Thunderbird, on Ubuntu 22.04)

I have set

```
message_size_limit = 90000000
```

in `postfix/main.cf` which works fine for just sending, which is SMTP. Copying into sent is IMAP, managed by courier but the email-size limit in postfix doesn't seem to affect IMAP settings for Courier

Comment: Please [quote the error you get in place of "the copy fails"](https://serverfault.com/posts/1102226/edit).

Comment: What is logged in the thunderbird error console (ctrl+shift+J)? You may be able to get a clearer picture if you try saving a Draft, instead of actually sending, since you are only interested in the IMAP upload part, not the SMTP send part that you assume is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increase the email-size limit in Courier for IMAP.

The Courier mail server uses several configuration files which are located in

```
/etc/courier
```

you must run courier restart for any changes to these files to take effect.

so this sets the limit to 99MB:

```
echo "103809024" > /etc/courier/sizelimit
service courier-imap-ssl restart
```

see: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/courier.8.html